# /dev name of already mounted device changes when a new USB device is inserted

Tags: linux, usb, mount

I mount USB devices using the following command. I have no `/etc/fstab` entry, I mount these devices programmatically.

```
mount -o nodev LABEL=xyz mount-point
```

As soon as I attach another USB device, the earlier device name which was used at mount (e.g. `/dev/sdc`) changes to a new name (e.g. `/dev/sdd`) and my mounted device will not be reachable (typically I receive an I/O error).

How can I avoid this behavior and force the system NOT to "rename" already mounted devices?

It would be VERY important that my device names stay in place.

Comment: The device name should not matter, as it is only used when mounting. (Even more, `mount` finds the correct device name for you, based on the label.) Once the filesystem has been mounted, Linux uses other means to identify the device. It's only a symptom, however; the real problem is that already-attached devices get reinitialized when a new one is plugged in, which is not supposed to ever happen in normal usage. If that is happening, there might be problems with USB itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding a rule to udev solves to problem. Before mounting the device I fetch the serial number of the device and write it into the udev rules.